How can I fix error on finding max value in matrix MIP?
I stuck on finding max value each column by writing constraint in MIP. Unfortunately, the error was
Error 59 Endogenous prod smin smax require model type

Error 256 equation eq2.. VAR prod smin smax

Suppose I have EM(f,t,i) as the positive variable, which is the result from previous constraints like this
      i1 i2 i3 i4 i5
f1.t1  7  5  6  0  6
f1.t2  8  4  6  1  6
f1.t3  6  7  3  2  4
f2.t1  8  7  5  3  1
f2.t2  0  5  5  7  0
f2.t3  0  8  0  5  9

My current coding:
eq2(f,i)..         last(i) =e= smax((t),EM(f,t,i));
So, I would like to fix the above coding and find the max value each column, and then collect in last(i) variable.
My target should be
last(1) = 8, last(2) = 8, last(3) = 6, last(4) = 7, last(5) = 9
Please help me to achieve this MIP model. Thank you.

To model
  y(i) = smax(j,x(i,j))

you need to do something like:
  y(i) >= x(i,j)               for all i,j
  y(i) <= x(i,j)+(1-δ(i,j))*M  for all i,j
  sum(j,δ(i,j)) = 1            for all i
  δ(i,j) ∈ {0,1}  (binary variables)

where M is a large enough constant. Often we can simplify things, but that depends on the rest of the model.
